# ngStorage: retrive data with variable key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I need some help...

I need to retrieve data from localstorage with ngStorage angular's plugin...

If I write

```
$localStorage.temp = [{ name: "Jhon", lastname: "Pitt"}];
var myVar = $localStorage.temp;
```

this is fine.... but If I write

```
var str = 'temp';
$localStorage.temp = [{ name: "Jhon", lastname: "Pitt"}];
var myVar = $localStorage.[str]; // this doesn't work
myVar = $localStorage.str; // this doesen't retrieve nothing cause there's no key 'str' in local storage
```

If I write this

```
var myVar = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(str));
```

It works, but I need to use $localStorage
How can I solve the problem? I need it so much...

Try it in my [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ldZSSTfpeieSieaqUYQz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close, but you had a syntax error on $localStorage.

Try:

```
var str = 'temp';
$localStorage.temp = [{ name: "Jhon", lastname: "Pitt"}];
var myVar = $localStorage[str]; // remove the .
```